# How to finish step between two levels with vinyl planks

Tags: stairs, trim, vinyl-flooring

I am hoping you can give me your opinions/suggestions/recommendations on how I should handle the finishing the step up to another level. I recently ripped up carpet and put vinyl plank boards down on the first level. The step up to the next level had carpet going up it. I am currently thinking I should cut a few pieces of the vinyl planks and use a nail gun and nail them into it and finish the bottom with a 1/4" round matching the vinyl finish? If I did this I don't know what to put on the top.

On the second level I will be putting the same vinyl planks down so was thinking I could use this

Option 1: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Zamma-Tupelo-Oak-Semi-Sweet-Oak-1-in-Thick-x-2-1-2-in-Wide-x-94-in-L-Vinyl-Stair-Nose-Molding-0157543918/308058242 but it seems ridiculously expensive and I would need two.

Would I be able to use this one instead?

Option 2:https://www.homedepot.com/p/Zamma-Tupelo-Oak-Semi-Sweet-Oak-7-16-in-Thick-x-1-3-4-in-Wide-x-72-in-Length-Vinyl-Carpet-Reducer-Molding-01571023918/308058253

Here is an image of what it currently looks like and what I am trying to finish:
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Thanks for any and all advice and tips you can give!

Dan

Comment: The first pic looks like a close-up of the 2nd (which is good!), however, the close up looks like you've got about 1", while in the 2nd it looks like the step is 4-6". Which is correct? Please [edit] your post to include the vertical dimension you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

The stair nose molding is twice as thick and 3/4" wider for a reason. It has to be stronger. Your second choice is meant to flush up against carpet on a flat floor and therefore doesn't need the strength that stepping up a stair would require. The wider stair nose is needed to keep the seam further away from the edge of the stair. You need the stair nose for this.